# Python queue linking object running asyncio coroutines with main thread input

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, python-asyncio

I have a script running where the main thread takes input from stdin and then passes it to a child thread using a queue. In the child thread I'm using asyncio coroutines to spin up a listener on a socket and wait for connections. Once a connection is made I can now send data through the listener from the main thread.

It all seems to work well enough, but since asyncio.BaseEventLoop is not thread safe am I going to run into problems?

This is my attempt to solve the problem of using a blocking library like python's cmd module with asyncio.

My code is below.

```
import sys
import asyncio
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

stdin_q = Queue()

clients = {} # task -> (reader, writer)

def client_connected_handler(client_reader, client_writer):
    # Start a new asyncio.Task to handle this specific client connection
    task = asyncio.Task(handle_client(client_reader, client_writer))
    clients[task] = (client_reader, client_writer)

    def client_done(task):
        # When the tasks that handles the specific client connection is done
        del clients[task]

    # Add the client_done callback to be run when the future becomes done
    task.add_done_callback(client_done)

@asyncio.coroutine
def handle_client(client_reader, client_writer):
    # Handle the requests for a specific client with a line oriented protocol
    while True:

        cmd = yield from get_input()
        client_writer.write(cmd.encode())

        data = yield from client_reader.read(1024)

        print(data.decode(),end="",flush=True)

@asyncio.coroutine
def get_input():
  while True:
    try:
      return stdin_q.get()
    except:
      pass



class Control:

    def start(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        server = self.loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.start_server(client_connected_handler, '0.0.0.0', 2222))
        self.loop.run_forever()
        self.stop()

    def stop(self):    
        self.loop.stop()
        self.loop.close()

def fire_control():
    con = Control()
    con.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    stdin_q.put("\n")
    t = Thread(target=fire_control)
    t.start()
    sleep(2)
    _cmd = ""
    while _cmd.lower() != "exit":
        _cmd = input("")
        if _cmd == "":
          _cmd = "\r\n"

        stdin_q.put(_cmd)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't going to work quite right, because the call to `stdin_q.get()` is going to block your event loop. This means that if your server has multiple clients, all of them will be completely blocked by whichever one happens to get to `stdin_q.get()` first, until you send data into the queue. The simplest way to get around this is  use [`BaseEvent.loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor) to run the `stdin_q.get` in a background `ThreadPoolExecutor`, which allows you to wait for it without blocking the event loop:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def get_input():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return (yield from loop.run_in_executor(None, stdin_q.get))  # None == use default executor.
```

**Edit (1/27/16):**

There is a library called [`janus`](https://github.com/aio-libs/janus), which provides an asyncio-friendly, thread-safe queue implementation.

Using that library, your code would look like this (I left out unchanged parts):

```
...
import janus

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
stdin_q = janus.Queue(loop=loop)
...

@asyncio.coroutine
def get_input():
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  return (yield from stdin_q.async_q.get())

class Control:

    def start(self):
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        server = self.loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.start_server(client_connected_handler, '0.0.0.0', 2222))
        self.loop.run_forever()
        self.stop()

    def stop(self):    
        self.loop.stop()
        self.loop.close()

...

if __name__ == "__main__":

    stdin_q.sync_q.put("\n")
    t = Thread(target=runner)
    t.start()
    sleep(2)
    _cmd = ""
    while _cmd.lower() != "exit":
        _cmd = input("")
        if _cmd == "":
          _cmd = "\r\n"

        stdin_q.sync_q.put(_cmd)
```

Comment: Interesting. You are a wealth of knowledge when it comes to asyncio. So if I wanted to send data to a specific connection would I just need to create a queue for each one to communicate between the main thread and child?

Comment: That is true, but you could also just use the `asyncio.Queue` which I think would allow you to `await stdin_q.get()`

Comment: @dalanmiller `asyncio.Queue` is not thread-safe, so it can't be used to pass values between threads. However, since I wrote this answer, I became aware of [`janus`](https://github.com/aio-libs/janus), which provides an asyncio-friendly, thread-safe queue implementation.

Comment: Ahh awesome. Out of curiosity, why use Threads _and_ coroutines in this context? Is there a performance benefit here?

Comment: @dalanmiller I think the OP was doing it so that they could read input from stdin in one thread,  and feed it into another thread running the event loop. The alternative would be to read from stdin in a non-blocking,  asyncio-friendly way. There's no performance benefit associated with either approach, using threads is just sometimes more convenient if you can't/don't want to use non-blocking I/O for something.

Comment: My use case was that I needed a command line user interface that could communicate with multiple connections coming into an asyncio listener. So for example, 4 connections come in, and I need to be able to connect to each one and interact just like a remote command line. This was my early stage research that was eventually incorporated into this project https://github.com/Rich5/Harness/blob/master/harness/modules/handlers/PSHandler.py

Comment: @dalanmiller There seems to be no cross-platform / clean way to do non-blocking read from the terminal. The only solution that worked for me was to spin a thread, do a blocking read there, and then put the result on the queue just like the OP did. Perhaps @dano can correct me and explain how I could instead read directly from `stdin` using `asyncio` API (I tried, but got stuck when it turned out that `sys.stdin` is not a socket in Windows).