# Is this the intended pattern for using Python `asyncio` coroutines?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to write a little concurrent stream handler with the Slack RTM API and I'm wondering if this is the most efficient use of Python coroutines. The `asyncio` package has a ton of options but it's hard to determine what is the correct approach for the project and the documentation I think doesn't do a very good job of explaining what the advantages/disadvantages are to each.

I think that I don't need to have the overhead of multiple threads here, and I need intercommunication between the async loops. Should I create a separate `BaseEventLoop` for each of my functions?

Being Python, I think there is a *near*-deterministic answer here to this question (`There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it`) but I'm afraid that adding all this asynchronous cruft may just make my code less performance than the completely sequential naive implementation.

```
# Is this the best way to communicate between coroutines? 
incoming_message_q = asyncio.Queue()

async def print_event():
    logging.info("Entering log loop")

    # Should this operate within it's own BaseEventLoop? 
    while True:
        event = await incoming_message_q.get()
        logging.info(event)

async def log_queue_status():
    while True:
        logging.info(incoming_message_q.qsize())
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

async def read_rtm_connection(client, q):
    if client.rtm_connect():
        logging.info("Successful Slack RTM connection")
        while True:

            # How do I make this part non-blocking?
            events = client.rtm_read()

            for event in events:
                logging.info("Putting onto the queue", event)
                if event["type"] == "presence_change":
                    await q.put(event)
                elif event["type"] == "message":
                    await q.put(event)
                else:
                    logging.info("Not sure what to do")

            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    else:
        logging.info("RTM connection failed.")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(print_event())
loop.create_task(log_queue_status())
loop.create_task(read_rtm_connection(client, incoming_message_q))
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Slack or what the rtm_read() method is, so with that in mind: To make something non-blocking it has to be an awaitable coroutine that you can run as an asyncio task using ensure_future(). If rtm_read() is not a coroutine, you could try wrapping it in a coroutine that somehow polls rtm_read() to take delivery of new events and pass them through to your other methods. Depending on your case, you could pass the event messages direct to the queue, or otherwise return a future each time an event is received and use a for-in loop inside a coroutine to iterate them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to interact with slack in an asyncio-friendly way, you're going to need to use a non-blocking API. I'm not sure what you're currently using, but if it doesn't include any `asyncio` coroutines, it's probably not going to be easily integrated into asyncio, unless you run all the blocking calls in a background thread, via `loop.run_in_executor`. The other option would be to actually convert all the underlying blocking I/O calls in the library to be non-blocking, which is generally a whole bunch of work.

The good news is that there is at least one library that has already done this work for you; [`slacker-asyncio`](https://github.com/gfreezy/slacker-asyncio/), which is a fork of `slacker`. You should be able to use that to interact with the RTM API via coroutines.

Comment: Thanks for the info @dano. I was looking at the slackhq/`python-slackclient` lib yesterday after I posted this and saw that it is indeed very blocking. If I ran that portion of the code in `loop.run_in_executor` as you say, what would be a safe way to communicate between coroutines and the `slackclient` thread?

Comment: @dalanmiller If you're just executing methods on the `client` object like in your above example, you can just do `events = loop.run_in_executor(None, client.rtm_read)`. `asyncio` will return the result from the `client.rtm_read()` call automatically.

Comment: If I have other `run_in_executor`s though going, would it be safe for them to also access the queues? AKA with `run_in_executor` I have to worry about thread-safety yes?

Comment: @dalanmiller In your example code, nothing is accessing the queue from outside of the event loop thread, so you'd be fine continuing to use `asyncio.Queue`. If you have code running in other threads that need to access the queue, you'd have to use either `threading.Queue` via `run_in_executor`, or the `janus` library's queue implementation (as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29349646/2073595)).

Comment: @dalanmiller Also, the code in my previous comment should have read `event = await loop.run_in_executor(None, client.rtm_read)`.

Comment: One more question @dano if you don't mind. Would it be more or less efficient to run the entire processing pipeline in a single `async` function? Or split it up into individual loops like I've done here? Or is it hard to say?

Comment: @dalanmiller Well, right now all your other loops do is print/log; they don't do anything asynchronous. So, there's no performance advantage gained by separating them from the main function. The overhead of sending data through the queue isn't huge, but obviously is higher than just logging directly in `read_rtm_connection`. I'd say that the queue is really only useful if you need to do some I/O that uses `await`.